# How to permutate numbers where repetition of immediate number is not allowed

Tags: permutations, combinations

Hi i have been studying permutation and combination i fell into a problem.
if You have a set of letters to choose from = {A,B,C,D}, and you must choose 3 of them, but no immediate repetition of a letter.

Example {A,B,A}, {C,D,C}, etc is allowed.

What formular, how should i solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first item in the resulting set we have $4$ choices.

For the second item in the set we have $4-1 = 3$ choices as we cannot repeat the previous letter.

Finally for the third item in the set we have $4-1= 3$ choices as again we cannot repeat the previous letter.

Multiplying the number of choices (using the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)) we have $4*3*3 = 36$ solutions.